# Android: animation

Tags: android

In my App I have an `ImageSwitcher`, and to buttons at the bottom (Next and Previous). I'm trying to set a smooth animation to `ImageSwitcher`, but everything looks awfully. Have any body knows smooth animation ? The best practice I think would be to create fade_in and fade_out animation...when I click next button first image should fade_in, and only after that next image should fade_out...But if to set to `ImageSwitcher` fade_in to AnimationIn and fade_out to animationOut, than when I will press next button fist image will fade_in and second image will fade_out at the same time, and that's looks awfully....Have any idea how to do that ? Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you do exactly like the [API sample ImageSwitcher1](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html).

If you don't like the overlaping of effects, you can add a `android:startOffset` to the fade in, so that it begins after the fade out of the previous image.